# Your connection is not secure should I add exception

Tags: security, firefox

For some time I have been using a site with no problems, as of yesterday
I get this:
Your connection is not secure
The owner of website.net has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Tor Browser has not connected to this website.

Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

Should I add an exception
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, unless you explicitly and fully understand what you are doing you should not set an exception.

As the warning clearly states, if you set an excpetion and unknowningly trust a site then you will open yourself up to having anything sent to that site from your browser read or manipulated by any entity in a position to tamper with the traffic content.